# xcode 7 could not build module 'X'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I updated to xcode 7 beta, but when I wanna try to install app onto my iphone not simulator, I got over 250+ errors, a lot of them says

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:707:2: Unsupported architecture
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:707:2: Unsupported architecture
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:707:2: Unsupported architecture
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:707:2: Unsupported architecture
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:707:2: Unsupported architecture
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:707:2: Unsupported architecture
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:707:2: Unsupported architecture
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:707:2: Unsupported architecture
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: Architecture not supported
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: Architecture not supported
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: Architecture not supported
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: Architecture not supported
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: Architecture not supported
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: Architecture not supported
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: Architecture not supported
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: Architecture not supported
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: Unknown type name '__int64_t'
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: Unknown type name '__int32_t'
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: Unknown type name '__int32_t'
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: Unknown type name '__uint32_t'
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: Unknown type name '__uint32_t'
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: Unknown type name '__uint64_t'; did you mean 'uint64_t'?
...
..
..
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:11:10: Could not build module 'Darwin'

/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:10: Could not build module 'CoreFoundation'

Could not build module 'Foundation'
Could not build module 'CoreBluetooth'
```

But it's ok on simulator.
And I already tried to change architecture to only armv7 and armv7s.

And also it works fine before I updated to xcode 7 beta, for now I cannot use xcode 6.x.

I reinstalled xcode 7 beta. Same thing.

Comment: have you tried arm64?

Comment: I tried remain arm64 only, it also didn't work.@Aggressor

Comment: Hmm for ours we have all 3 listed. Not sure whats up :?

Comment: Are you building a package or are you just building a debug to the phone?

Comment: I'm building a debug to my device. It totally works fine in simulator.

Comment: I've encountered this problem from xcode7 beta 1 till now. @Aggressor

Comment: Sorry I have absolutely no idea. As a pure shot in the dark, you could trie removing files 1 by 1 trying to make it work... just to see the offending file and maybe that will give a hint